# Why I can't see the secrets in the output when when viewing the Service Account

Tags: kubernetes

I have created the following objects in my `minikube` setup

- ServiceAccount
- Secret
- Role
- RoleBinding

When I try try to get the ServiceAccount using `kubectl get sa`, I get the following output:

```
➜  ~ k get sa
NAME      SECRETS   AGE
...
test      0         4m13s
```

And it says `0` secrets. Here is how I imperatively created the above objects

```
kubectl create sa test
```

```
➜  ~ kubectl apply -f - <<EOF
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: test
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/service-account.name: test
type: kubernetes.io/service-account-token
EOF
```

can someone help me understand why it is not showing?

Thank you!

Comment: What's K8s Version are you Using?

Comment: @RaviKyada: 1.26.6

Answer (score 0):

From K8s 1.24 Kubernetes doesn't Create a Secret Token Automatically. and its from their Version based upgradation. [Checkout their Changelog of 1.24.](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/CHANGELOG/CHANGELOG-1.24.md#urgent-upgrade-notes)

So After 1.24, You need to Do a workaround to create a Secret for the ServicesAccount. As They Mentions in Changelog that **Secret API objects containing service account tokens are no longer auto-generated for every ServiceAccount.**

You can Create a Service Account Secret Like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
type: kubernetes.io/service-account-token
metadata:
  name: test
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/service-account.name: test
type: kubernetes.io/service-account-token
```

As You had made ServiceAccount with name `test` Your Secret name should also match.

**If you don't want to manage files then you can Go with a single command that will work smoothly.**

```
kubectl create token test
```

This will Create JWT Token for your Service Account.

This is also Best Practice for Any Service Account Creation but Earlier K8s 1.24 they are creating it Automatically.

Comment: Hi, thank you for this. isn't this what I have done already? Just curious what is new in your answer.

Comment: check now, just ```type: kubernetes.io/service-account-token``` is missing

Comment: It is already there in my question :)